# How do i refer to an attribute that my form is manipulating from within my form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, attributes, metadata

I’m using Rails 4.2.5.  I have a field in my users model named “user_file_id”.  In my “app/views/users/edit.html.erb” page, I’m iterating over a series of images and if one of the image id’s matches the field in my model, I would like to add a class to the image tag.  So I’m trying the below …

```
<%= form_for(@user, :method => :put) do |f| %>
…
  <div class="profileField">
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_file_id %>
    <p>Choose Your Avatar<p/>
    <div><% @avatar_files.each do |image| %>
      <%= image_tag "avatar_images/#{image.file.split('/').last}", height:100, class:"avatar_file #{image.id == user_file_id ? 'selected' : ''}", :data => { :id => image.id } %>
    <% end %></div>
  </div>
```

but I’m getting the Rails error

```
undefined local variable or method `user_file_id' for #<#<Class:0x007ff0b98223f8>:0x007ff0b57f2490>
```

From within my Rails form, how do I refer to an attribute that the form is manipulating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
f.object.user_file_id
```

`f.object` works with SimpleForm - and I believe it's the same with Rails default form helper.